# Cannot find module 'swagger_params_parser'

Tags: node.js, npm, swagger, swagger-node-runner

I have a Swagger NodeJS project which was created using [Swagger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger)

Swagger uses swagger-connect 0.1.0 out of the box but I've now upgraded to swagger-connect 0.7.0 using the [manual instructions](https://github.com/theganyo/swagger-node-runner/releases/tag/v0.6.0) which included adding the following to config/default.yml:

```
_swagger_params_parser:                    # <= Add this definition
  name: swagger_params_parser
  jsonOptions: {}
  urlencodedOptions:
    extended: false
  multerOptions:
    inMemory: true
  textOptions:
    type: "*/*"
```

and under section 'swagger_controllers:' I've added :

```
 - swagger_params_parser
```

This works gloriously on my local machine but when I push to the server it throws the error:

```
Error initializing middleware
May 22 13:25:27 myserver "myapp": Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/myapp/node_modules/swagger-connect/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/node_modules/bagpipes/lib/fittings/swagger_params_parser'
```

I'm starting the server via:

```
node app.js
```

So it looks like a potential dependency bleed on my local machine but I've destroyed (rm -Rf) 'node_modules' and re-run `npm install` and it still works fine on my local machine but breaks on the server.

Any ideas why swagger-params-parser is missing?

Also, another weird thing is that swagger-params-parser **doesn't** exist locally in directory '`/var/www/myapp/node_modules/swagger-connect/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/node_modules/bagpipes/lib/fittings/swagger_params_parser`' and yet locally it works!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a stray `node_modules` directory on the server (we normally use `node_modules_production`).

Two things I've learned from this:

1.) `node_modules` is used instead of `node_module_production` if it exists. My RPM was not overwriting the directory and hence left an old copy of `node_modules` which was incorrectly packaged up at some point. The swagger app was loading modules from `node_modules` and not `node_modules_production`

2.) swagger_params_parser is indeed **missing**, even on the working version of the code so it looks like this error:

```
Error initializing middleware
May 22 13:25:27 myserver "myapp": Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/myapp/node_modules/swagger-connect/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/node_modules/bagpipes/lib/fittings/swagger_params_parser
```

is misleading, as that module is never present, at least in version 0.7.0 of `swagger-connect`